# LWJGL natives os + JPMS + GRADLE

Tags: java, gradle, lwjgl, java-platform-module-system

> **ERROR: UnsatisfiedLinkError**

```
[LWJGL] Failed to load a library. Possible solutions:
    a) Add the directory that contains the shared library to -Djava.library.path or -Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath.
    b) Add the JAR that contains the shared library to the classpath.
[LWJGL] Enable debug mode with -Dorg.lwjgl.util.Debug=true for better diagnostics.
[LWJGL] Enable the SharedLibraryLoader debug mode with -Dorg.lwjgl.util.DebugLoader=true for better diagnostics.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to locate library: lwjgl.dll
    at org.lwjgl/org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:162)
    at org.lwjgl/org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:62)
    at org.lwjgl/org.lwjgl.system.Library.<clinit>(Library.java:50)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw/org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.<clinit>(GLFW.java:674)
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

> I tried to had/implement the java platform module system to one of my
> projects and this linking error had me. The following lines are build script and the module-info src code.

> **lib** module: *buld.gradle*.kts

```
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.support.unzipTo

plugins {
    `java-library`
}
group = "com.moc"
version = "0.0"
java {
    modularity.inferModulePath.set(true)
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
val nativesClasses: Configuration by configurations.creating {
    isTransitive = false
    extendsFrom(configurations.runtimeOnly.get())
}
tasks.register("unzips") {
    nativesClasses.asFileTree.forEach {
        unzipTo(File("${buildDir}/libs/natives"), it)
    }
}
dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.1")

    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
    
    implementation(fileTree("hard-typed/path/for/the/lwjgl-3.2.3/lwjgl.jar") )
    implementation(fileTree("hard-typed/path/for/the/lwjgl-3.2.3/lwjgl-glfw.jar") )
    implementation(fileTree("hard-typed/path/for/the/lwjgl-3.2.3/lwjgl-assimp.jar") )
    implementation(fileTree("hard-typed/path/for/the/lwjgl-3.2.3/lwjgl-opengl.jar") )

    runtimeOnly( fileTree("hard-typed/path/for/the/lwjgl-3.2.3/lwjgl-natives-windows.jar" ) )
    runtimeOnly( fileTree("hard-typed/path/for/the/lwjgl-3.2.3/wjgl-glfw-natives-windows.jar" ) )
    runtimeOnly( fileTree("hard-typed/path/for/the/lwjgl-3.2.3/lwjgl-assimp-natives-windows.jar" ) )
    runtimeOnly( fileTree("hard-typed/path/for/the/lwjgl-3.2.3/lwjgl-opengl-natives-windows.jar" ) )
}
tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

> **app** module: *build.gradle*.kts

```
plugins {
    application
}
group = "com.moc"
version = "0.0"
java {
    modularity.inferModulePath.set(true)
}
application {
    mainModule.set("moc.app")
    mainClass.set("com.moc.main.App")
}
tasks.withType<JavaExec> {
    System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath",
        "hard-typed/path/of/natives-os/lwjgl;" +
                "hard-typed/path/of/natives-os/opengl;" +
                "hard-typed/path/of/natives-os/glfw;" +
                "hard-typed/path/of/natives-os/assimp" )
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":lib"))
}
```

> **lib & app** module: *module-info*.java

```
module moc.lib {
    requires org.lwjgl.glfw;
    requires org.lwjgl.opengl;
    requires org.lwjgl.assimp;
    exports com.moc;
}
module moc.app {
    requires moc.lib;
}
```

**> How do we link this natives os to our project by using a gradle build script and without any external plugins?**

Answer (score 0):

> I tried this one and it's working but somehow I feel this is not the right way?

```
tasks.withType<JavaExec> {
    val lwjgl = System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", "../libs/natives"
    systemProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", System.getProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath") )
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> And try this one for the application extension

```
val lwjgNativesProp : String? = System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypathz", "../libs/natives")

application {
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = arrayListOf("-Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath=${System.getProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypathz")}")
}

tasks.withType<JavaExec> {
    lwjglNativesProp?.let { systemProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", it) }
}
```